# Android Popup Menu Shadow

Tags: android, menu, popup, shadow

I created this popup menu but the background shadow is missing. How can I add some? It would be cool if the shadow is only on the left and the bottom.

Here is a picture: You can see that the color of the popup and the background of the activity below the toolbar go hand in hand.

[image: picture]

Here is my code:

**acitivity snippet**

```
public void showPopup(final MenuItem menuItem) {
        View view = findViewById(R.id.action_alarm);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] functions = {getString(R.string.benachrichtigung), getString(R.string.benachrichtigungUm)};
        final ListAdapter adapter = new CustomPopupAdapter(this, functions, listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) listView.getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
                showTimePickerDialog(tv);
            }
        });

        PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view);
    }
```

**popup.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.shadow_192256));
        } else {
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.shadow_192256));
        }
```

Comment: You can change background of RelativeLayout to a photo or shape with shadow.

Comment: @tinysunlight can you post an example pls?

Comment: you can use the popupwindow rather then popupmenu ,popupwindow has more feature then popupmenu

Comment: Use this layout https://github.com/ShogoMizumoto/ZDepthShadow  as parent Layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem few days ago :) This is how I solved it. Below link will take you to a website where you can generate a shadow whatever you want :)

http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/

This is a 9 patch image :) Once done all you have to do is :)

```
  Display display = (yourActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
  Point size = new Point();
  display.getSize(size);
  int width = size.x;
  int height = size.y;

  Resources resources = yourActivity.getResources();
  int navigationBarHeight = 0;
  int statusbarHeight = 0;
  int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
  if (resourceId > 0) {
      navigationBarHeight = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
   }

  resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
  if (resourceId > 0) {
       statusbarHeight = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            }
 popupWindow = new PopupWindow(yourActivity);
 popupWindow.setContentView(yourlayout);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.shadow, yourActivity.getTheme()));
            } else {
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.shadow));
            }
            popupWindow.setWidth(width - 20);//20 is padding i have added 10 from right 10 from left
            popupWindow.setHeight(height - (navigationBarHeight +40));
            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);   
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(youractivityView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, statusbarHeight);
```

Thats it :) You are done :)

Comment: getDrawable() requires api 21. My min is 16.

Comment: if you still have problem try this ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***) Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796246/android-alternative-for-context-getdrawable

Comment: You can have a look at this as well :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22/29041466#29041466

Comment: Ok ContextCompat works. But the shadow does not show up.

Comment: Ok :) One samll change :) You cant use   popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view); instead use popupWindow.showAtLocation()

Comment: @oliver-u check the updated code dude, please change getDrawable to the one specified in link

Comment: What is youractivityView? how i get the right height and width?

Comment: yourActivityView is the view on which you want to show the popupWindow like if its a listView you can say this.listView

Comment: its the menuitem at the top

Comment: you must have inflated the view right which you might have set as your activity contentview pass the same

Comment: @Oliver U : check the updated answer . I have written everything how to specify height width x and y coordinate everything. Copy paste everything it should be fine dude :) Just pass you activity layout view where I have mentioned yourActivityView thats all

Comment: Ok I got it. But its placed in the middle of the screen. I want it like on the picture above^^

Comment: just play with x and y co-ordinate bro :) rather then 0 specify 40 in showAtLocation and try modifying Gravity.RIGHT :) shouldnt that do???

Comment: Always welcome man :) Happy that I could help :) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the most straightforward way to do this is by setting the view's elevation, which is available in API 21 and above.  This is what worked well for me:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    popupWindow.setElevation(10);
}
```