# getDrawable(int) is deprecated warning in this line: Drawable res = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(item.img_resId);

Tags: java, android, deprecated

I have created my own custom adapter. In this code I get getDrawable(int) is deprecated warning in this line: `Drawable res = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(item.img_resId);`.

**I go through these:**

[Android getResources().getDrawable() deprecated API 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22/29041466)

[Android: Alternative for context.getDrawable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796246/android-alternative-for-context-getdrawable)

But none of them has work in my case.

**My code:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemDataObject> {
private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView img;
    TextView title;
    TextView sub_title;
}

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemDataObject> list_item_details) {
    super(context, 0, list_item_details);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    ItemDataObject item = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
    if (convertView == null) {
        // If there's no view to re-use, inflate a brand new view for row
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.img = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        viewHolder.title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        viewHolder.sub_title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubTitle);
        // Cache the viewHolder object inside the fresh view
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // View is being recycled, retrieve the viewHolder object from tag
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Populate the data from the data object via the viewHolder object into the template view.
    assert item != null;
    Drawable res = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(item.img_resId);
    viewHolder.img.setImageDrawable(res);
    viewHolder.title.setText(item.title);
    viewHolder.sub_title.setText(item.subtitle);
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly did the answers in those linked posts not work? Also, why are you retrieving the `Drawable` yourself? That is, why not just use `ImageView#setImageResource()`?

Comment: @MikeM. first link given in question will work. btw link is [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22/29041466](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22/29041466)

Comment: Do you have access to `context` in the `Adapter`? Also, you may use `ImageView::setImageResource` for your purposes here.

Comment: I don't understand. If the answers in the first link work, why are you asking this question?

Comment: @MikeM. I think you are unable to open the first link so I write that it will work. Actually, answers have not fit for my problem. Btw now I got the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you should use

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.my_drawable);
```

Where `this` is your passed `context` if you are using a widget, just `this` if you are calling from an Activity, or `getActivity()` if you are calling from Fragment

In your case, when you are initializing your Widget also save your `Context` instance:

```
Context context;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemDataObject> list_item_details) {
    super(context, 0, list_item_details);
    this.context = context;
}
```

Now you are able to call:

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.my_drawable);
```

Comment: this should not work. It shows wrong 1st argument type as an error.

Comment: @NileshRathod not at all. This solution also given in 1st link in my question but not work in my case.

Comment: @Ricardo now it will work. But still an error in the answer that in contructor CustomAdapter `super()` must be in the first line.